# Should WSL be a synonym for Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki-suggestion

I noticed today that we currently have two tags for the same Windows 10 feature.

- [WSL](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wsl)
- [Windows-Subsystem-For-Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-subsystem-for-linux).

My suggestion is for WSL tag to become a synonym of the greater `Windows Subsystem for Linux` tag.  Worth pointing out that we already have several synonyms associated with the `Windows Subsystem for Linux` tag.

However, the tag description of WSL, is more accurate than the current description of `Windows Subsystem for Linux`

Comment: Seems reasonable. Especially as many users will not recognise WSL and Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Comment: @reben - I used the word "tags" no less than 5 times.

Comment: @reben In the future when you realize something like you missed something obviously don’t comment about it.  Noisy commentary is not helpful.  Shouldn’t have even replied to your comment.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seems a good call and no reason to have two nearly identical tags.  I've gone ahead and merged them.

I've also copied the excerpt from [wsl](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wsl) to [windows-subsystem-for-linux](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-subsystem-for-linux)

```
updating post history, 12 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 12 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 8 rows affected
updating Documentation tag proposal commitments, 0 rows affected
updating DocTags, 0 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, new count: 248
tag remapping of [windows-subsystem-for-linux] and [wsl] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym wsl -> windows-subsystem-for-linux was approved!
```

Comment: That looks like very low level database messages.